# Deduce a statement from either one or two statements?

Tags: real-analysis

In the following, I am referring to [this source, page 6](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekaplicky/pages/pages/2020l/matthes_entropymethods.pdf).

It is shown that

(1) $\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{2\lambda t}(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty])\right)\leq 0$

(2) $\Vert u-u_\infty\Vert^2\leq\frac{2}{\lambda}(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty])$

Do I need both statements (1) and (2) to deduce that

$$
H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty]\leq e^{-2\lambda t}\cdot (H[u(0)]-H[u_\infty])\tag{*}
$$

or is (1) enough to deduce $(*)$?

It seems to me that (1) is enough to deduce $(*)$ because (1) already means that $H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty]$ decays at least with rate $e^{-2\lambda t}$.

On the other hand, (2) seems also to be important as it says something like "The difference between $u(t)$ and $u_\infty$ decays with a comparable rate". Maybe one needs this additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Intuition is a valuable thing, but in instances like these, one needs to move from intuition to actual calculation. In this case, if we set $F(t) = e^{2\lambda t} \bigl( H[u(t)] - H[u_\infty] \bigr)$, then (1) says that $F(t)$ is decreasing, and therefore $F(t) \le F(0)$ for $t\ge0$; this inequality is
$$
e^{2\lambda t} \bigl( H[u(t)] - H[u_\infty] \bigr) \le e^{2\lambda\cdot0} \bigl( H[u(0)] - H[u_\infty] \bigr),
$$
which is equivalent to (*). (Note that the assumption $t\ge0$ is crucial.)

Comment: The reason why I mentioned (2) is the following: Later in the cited link, on page 10, it is said that (1.19), which is $H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty]\leq e^{-t}(H[u(0)]-H[u_\infty])$, is a consequence of (1.21) **and** Proposition 1.1. It is also said that (1.21) directly implies that
$$
e^t(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty])
$$
is decreasing in the sense you wrote. But as you said this already implies (1.19). So why do we additionally need Proposition 1.1 which says that
$$
\Vert u-u_\infty\Vert\leq C(H[u(t)]-H[u_\infty])^{1/2},
$$
 to deduce (1.19)?